# Looking for an old classic Christian card game

Tags: children

This may be the wrong place for this question, but the gaming crowd may be the wrong place for the answer. I'm happy to delete it if necessary.

We became Christians as a family together over 20 years ago, and had a Christian card game called "Kingdom". I know it was an uncommon game when we bought it in the late 1990s or early 2000s, and now I've tried several searches for it, and have come up dry. I think it has the word "Kingdom" written on the left edge of each card. I don't think there was any kind of a board associated with it. Anyone have any ideas? I've searched Google, eBay, Google images, and more, to no avail.

Thanks!

Comment: religious boardgames: https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamecategory/1115/religious/linkeditems/boardgamecategory

Comment: do you have any other details about the game: goal, deck size, players, etc

Comment: @depperm Thanks for the questions! The deck was a similar size to a deck of face cards, but perhaps slightly smaller. I think there were clouds on the case of the deck and maybe a cross in the design, but at least the clouds and the word "Kingdom". We had four in our family, so at least four players, but I don't remember the goal.